# Files not being copied to media/ folder

Tags: component

I'm creating a component. I have put the images, css files, javascript files and other assets in com_mycomponent/media folder. And in my manifest file I have added this:

```
<media destination="com_mycomponent" folder="media">
    <filename>index.html</filename>
    <folder>css</folder>
    <folder>font-awesome</folder>
    <folder>images</folder>
    <folder>js</folder>
</media>
```

However, when I access the server, inside the `media/com_mycomponent`, the directories and files are not there, the directory is completely empty.

My component directory structure is:

```
.
+-- admin/
+-- media/
+-- site/
+-- mycomponent.xml
```

Directory permission is `755` and it's to the user `www-data`.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your full xml file

Comment: Check your `/media/com_mycomponent` folder permissions. Your code looks correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem. In my xml file I was adding `index.html` in the `<filename>` tag, however there was no `index.html` file in `media/` directory.

So basically, everything listed in the xml file must exist in the directory as well.

Comment: The `index.html` must be in the folder for security reason

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add it do the `media/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, place media folder at the "root" of your component directory structure - and not in any deeper location.

Then in the manifest file, try the following:

```
<media destination="mycomponent" folder="media/mycomponent">
    <filename>index.html</filename>
    <folder>css</folder>
    <folder>font-awesome</folder>
    <folder>images</folder>
    <folder>js</folder>
</media>
```

Comment: But it is in the root of my component directory. I misstyped it, sorry. Tried your solution but it didn't work. Still not copying the files and folders.